# Get values from nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need help getting the values from this array.

I have this from a mysql db

```
Array ( [Descuento] => D.L. 25897 AFP [0] => D.L. 25897 AFP [Monto] => 69.2000 [1] => 69.2000 [Nombre] => MARLENE JESUS [2] => MARLENE JESUS )

Array ( [Descuento] => Tardanzas [0] => Tardanzas [Monto] => 0.0500 [1] => 0.0500 [Nombre] => MARLENE JESUS [2] => MARLENE JESUS )

Array ( [Descuento] => Inasistencias [0] => Inasistencias [Monto] => 24.4900 [1] => 24.4900 [Nombre] => MARLENE JESUS [2] => MARLENE JESUS )

Array ( [Descuento] => Cafae-SE [0] => Cafae-SE [Monto] => 16.3000 [1] => 16.3000 [Nombre] => MARLENE JESUS [2] => MARLENE JESUS )
```

I get this from a Mysql query

```
SELECT Dscto01 AS Descuento, Mto01 AS Monto, NOMBRES AS Nombre
FROM  data WHERE Dscto01 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto02, Mto02, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto02 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto03, Mto03, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto03 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto04, Mto04, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto04 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto05, Mto05, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto05 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto06, Mto06, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto06 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto07, Mto07, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto07 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto08, Mto08, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto08 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto09, Mto09, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto09 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto10, Mto10, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto10 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto11, Mto11, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto11 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto12, Mto12, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto12 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto13, Mto13, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto13 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto14, Mto14, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto14 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto15, Mto15, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto15 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto16, Mto16, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto16 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto17, Mto17, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto17 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto18, Mto18, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto18 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto19, Mto19, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto19 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni
                                                                    UNION ALL
                                                                    SELECT Dscto20, Mto20, NOMBRES
                                                                    FROM  data
                                                                    WHERE Dscto20 IS NOT NULL AND DNI = :dni LIMIT :start,:end'
```

And then

```
foreach($result as $row) {
                    print_r ($row);}
```

In the first array the [Descuento] result should be D.L. 25897 AFP and the [Monto] 69.2000
I need to put the [Descuento] in a variable and the [Monto] also. Can you please help me. I cant access that info.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the relevant PHP code that generates this array?

Comment: its a mysql query and a foreach($result as $row) {
                        print_r ($row); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each iteration you can access the elements directly using `$row['Descuento']` so something like...

```
foreach ( $result as $row ) {
   $descuento = $row['Descuento'];
   $monto = $row['Monto'];
   // Do something with values
}
```

The one thing is that each loop will overwrite the last value, so I've added the `// do something here` as it's commonly seen questions about 'why do I just have the last set of values after loop'.